# How to remove drivers from windows using a recovery USB?

Tags: windows-10, command-line

I have created a bootable Windows 10 media.

Following instructions on deleting drivers on stack overflow I have booted into this and opened command prompt (shift F10)

However I am having some issues.

I have a list of the third party drivers here. I would like to delete **oem1.inf** for example.

[image]

So according to various sites, I can use the **dism** command.

My current path is c:\Windows\System32 (it was X:\Sources)

I have tried multiple commands from online:

```
dism /image:c: /delete-driver /driver:oem1.inf

Error: 2
Unable to access image. 
Make sure that the path and the Windows directory for the image exist and you have Read permissions on the folder
```

So I try the next one:

```
dism /image:c:\ /remove-driver /driver:oem1.inf
Error: 2
Unable to access image. 
Make sure that the path and the Windows directoy for the image exist and you have Read permissions on the folder
```

Another stack overflow comment recommended `pnputil`

So I logged into windows and tried:

```
pnputil -f -d oem1.inf

Deleting driver package failed: One or more devices are presently installed using the specified INF
```

By the way, I got that table from running `dism /online /get-drivers /format:table` in windows. It does not work while in recovery. I get the error ' Deoployment Image Servicing and Management Tool. Error 87. get-drivers option is unknown'

I have admin rights.

I am running out of ideas. I just want to delete some drivers.

Comment: Are you sure C: is the system drive? The letters may be different when booting from other media.

Comment: Windows is probably on `D:`. The `C:` drive-letter is reserved to the boot device.